# AppendAllText doesnt save new lines from textbox1.text into .txt file

Tags: vb.net, file, text

I can't get why the File.AppendAllText doesn't save New lines into txt. For example Textbox1.text contains:

```
Textbox1.text &= "hello, it's me, first lane" & Environment.NewLine
Textbox1.text &= "hello, it's me, second lane" & Environment.NewLine
```

And the code:

```
Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    Dim saveFile1 As New SaveFileDialog()

    saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.txt"
    saveFile1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt"

    ' Determine if the user selected a file name from the saveFileDialog.
    If (saveFile1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) _
        And (saveFile1.FileName.Length) > 0 Then

        ' Save the contents of the TextBox into the file.

        File.AppendAllText(saveFile1.FileName,
        TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

And the textbox output:

> hello, it's me, first lanehello, it's me, second lane

I'm opening with default notepad. If I open the file with wordpad or windows office, new lines exist. So how to make notepad see the new lines

Comment: Firstly, why does your title say `AppendAllLines` while you question and code say `AppendAllText`?  It's not a big deal on this occasion but inconsistencies like that might be a big problem on other occasions.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yeah sorry jm, i miss spelled

Comment: What does "default windows note" actually mean?

Comment: At a guess, I would say that you are displaying the text as HTML.  Something that renders HTML doesn't treat carriage returns and line feeds as line breaks.

Comment: Actually, are you saying that the `TextBox` itself is not displaying multiple lines?  If so, did you set its `Multiline` property to `True`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, of cause multiline property is true. default windows note means that I'm opening the .txt with the simplest program which called "Note" it exists on all windows versions. For Textbox1.text it displays everything correctly with new lanes in debugging, but when I save the content of textbox to text file the newlines doesnt show up on file.

Comment: OK, you're not making sense. There is no program in Windows called "Note". The basic text editor in Windows is named "Notepad" but you specifically stated that Notepad displays the file as expected.  If the `TextBox` shows the line breaks and some other application(s) shows the line breaks then the line breaks are there.  If some specific application isn't displaying them then that's an issue with that application, not your VB code so it's not a question for here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  yes notepad, I confused it with WordPad. So the correct question would be that NotePad doesn't show new lines, and WordPad and Microsoft Office does.

Comment: I just tested your exact code and I saw separate lines in Notepad, WordPad and Word.  I'm using Windows 10 v1809 but I can't see why earlier versions should be any different.

Comment: @jmcilhinney this is totally strange, because I have the newest version of win10 and  I don't have separate lines on a notepad

Comment: @jmcilhinney okay, I've tested on another PC with windows10. The same problem with NotePad. What's the case? My .net version is 4.0

Comment: The newest version of Notepad supports different line break formats.  You're using CRLF there so I would have thought that, if there was an issue, you'd see more lines rather than fewer.  When you open the file, what does the status bar say the line break format is?

Comment: I just tested against .NET 4.0 using a new file and existing files using CRLF and LF as line breaks and every test worked fine for me.

Comment: @jmcilhinney my notepad doesn't have a status bar. Its just while text screen and few menu options on the top

Comment: "TextBox1" seems very misleading.  RichTextBox uses non-standard line-endings for histerical reasons.  Best way to save its content is to [ask it to do it itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_RichTextBox_SaveFile_System_String_System_Windows_Forms_RichTextBoxStreamType_).  Use RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText to get a file that Notepad will be happy with.

Comment: Damn and blast! I didn't notice the references to RTF and `RichTextBox` in the code comments.  If you are using a `RichTextBox` then it will be using just LF as line breaks rather than CRLF. As I've pointed out, Notepd in the latest version of Windows 10 does actually support just CR or just LF as line breaks so it appears that you actually are NOT using the latest version of Windows 10.  You are probably on 1803 rather than 1809. In that case you have misled me twice in this thread.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm using the textbox. The comments mislead, sorry. And i tried Environment.NewLine and vbCr and vbLf and vbCrLf, nothing works

Comment: In that case, I have no explanation.  I would suggest that you actually read the file using code and examine the actual characters using the debugger.  If you're using `Environment.NewLine` then you should be getting CRLF but the fact that Notepad doesn't recognise the line breaks while WordPad and Word seems to suggest that you're getting LF only.  That said, if you're explicitly using `vbCrLf` then something would have to be explicitly stripping out the carriage returns somewhere... but where?  I'm stumped.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thx for your precious time, but as you are the god of .net (at least for me, I'm looking at your overflow activity for a long time) and we have not found a solution. I  decided to change .txt extension to .rtf, and because of that the file will be opened by Microsoft Word, and it shows all new lines. Yeah, it's not what I was looking for, but at least its something. Thanks again